# Is it possible to use multiple '.where()' statements in querying data from firebase using flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm relatively new to flutter and firebase. I am trying to nest `.where()` statements to better filter the results of my query.

In my code, I want to query document/s that have an id field included in an array, and the same case is with the displayName field. Have any suggestions on how I can create more complex queries?

```
  Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> searchFriend(String loggedInUserId,
      String searchString, List<dynamic> idOfFriends) async {
    List<dynamic> searchParse = searchString.split(' ');
  

    Stream<QuerySnapshot> searchResult = await db
        .collection('Users')
        .where('id', whereIn: idOfFriends)
        .where('displayName', whereIn: searchParse)
        .snapshots();
        
    return searchResult;
  }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code as *text* rather than as an image.

Comment: can be used multiple where but firebase not allowed to use complex query like sql, one collection to another collection connectivity...

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple where but keep the limitations in mind while writing your queries as per firestore documentation.

Please follow official documentation about limitations:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations

From there:

> You can use at most one `in`, `not-in`, or `array-contains-any` clause per query.

So you can't have two `whereIn` conditions in a single query.